# Can I access a cookie created by a servlet in a html page?

Tags: java, html, servlets

I am trying to create a booking form that needs the User ID in all the pages. I wanted to know how to handle session when I redirect the pages as [HTML->servlet->HTML]

Comment: Please share, what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can used *[HttpSession.setAttribute](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#setAttribute(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object))* & *[HttpSession.getAttribute](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#getAttribute(java.lang.String))* for eg:

JSP Page :

```
       //getting id value 
        String id= request.getParameter("user_id");
        //the variable which is set in session scope you can use anywhere 
         request.getSession().setAttribute("id",id);
          request.getRequestDispatcher("/yourServleturl").forward(request,response);
```

Now to get that `session` attribute write like below in `servlet` :

```
   HttpSession session=request.getSession();
      //getting value in session
    String id=session.getAttribute("id").toString();
    //do further processing
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: Does this session live even if I navigate through various html pages?

Comment: Yes until you have not `unset` it , it will remain set only .